# Javascript text box hover on mouse over and on mouse click

Tags: javascript, textbox

This question is about the 'Javascript text box hover on mouse over' code on [this page](http://jsfiddle.net/Mchhs/)

script:

```
var oVTog = {
toggle: function (el) {

    var container  = el.parentNode;
    var para = container.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];  
    para.style.display = "none";

    el.onmouseover = function () {
                  para.style.display = '';
                  return false;
            };
    el.onmouseout = function () {
                  para.style.display = 'none';
                  return false;
            };
    el.onclick = function () {
                  para.style.display = para.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none';
                  return false;
            };
    }
};
window.onload = function () {
var l = document.getElementById('togTrigger');
oVTog.toggle(l);
var l = document.getElementById('togTrigger2');
oVTog.toggle(l);
};
```

My question is: This is also works on mouseclick. How can i get it to work so that a mouseclick makes the text box stay open and close it again? Clicking it should set it to a clicked state or something because i also want the mouse-over option to work when you haven't clicked on it yet. I like the mouseover option and it should be retained but i want to be able to keep the box open so i can use the content inside it (copy it, click links, etc.)

Basically this is the scenario i want;
I want to be able to:

1. mouse over the text or button to open the hovering text box.
2. click the text or button to keep the text box open
3. now the box stays open and mouse over doesnt work anymore
4. click on the text or button again to close the box
5. and enable mouse over again

Comment: Are you sure you want to disable clicking? There is no such thing as hovering on touch-screens. That's why the handler is run when clicked.

Comment: No i want to use the clicking to keep the box open, while also retaining the function to open it on mouse-over. I edited the question a little so you might understand it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mchhs/3/).

I have added a variable called `isClicked`. By setting it when you click, I can ignore hiding the element on the `mouseout` handler.

```
var oVTog = {
    toggle: function (el) {
        var container  = el.parentNode;
        var para = container.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
        para.style.display = "none";

        // create variable
        var isClicked = false;

        el.onmouseover = function () {
            para.style.display = '';
            return false;
        };
        el.onmouseout = function () {
            // ignore if button was clicked
            if(!isClicked)
                para.style.display = 'none';

            return false;
        };
        el.onclick = function () {
            // if it's clicked, change it to TRUE
            // if it's clicked again, change it back to FALSE

            isClicked = !isClicked; // toggle

            para.style.display = ((isClicked) ? '' : 'none');
            return false;
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: @Martina no he wouldn't, because `isClicked` is defined in it's own scope. It only applies to the element that is passed as argument.

Comment: Ah indeed. very sorry, my bad.

Comment: Actually here is the page i want to use it on. http://jsfiddle.net/Mchhs/6/
The boxes are in the first menu item 'Openen DBC' (and in the submenus), the rest are filler for now. I'm new to javascript but managed to create this anyway